# Can you run Resharper 4.5 and 5.0 Beta side-by-side?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, resharper

i see they have a version of resharper for vs 2010

http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+5.0+Nightly+Builds

can i install this for my vs 2010 development and keep 4.5 for my vs 2008 development of will these conflict?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have resharper 5.0 installed in vs2010 beta2 and resharper 4.5 in vs2008. They both work just fine. Just make sure to uncheck the "install vs2008 integration" checkbox when installing resharper 5.